# Asp.Net Mvc Entity Framework Deserialized object Linq query null object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, deserialization

I deserialize JSON file into my Entity Classes. for simplify, Let's assume these are my classes

```
public class Result{
 ...
 public List<Sens> senses { get; set; }
}
public class Sens{
...    
 public Object definition { get; set; }
 }
```

After I deserialize my JSON into a Result Object I insert to database. There is no error and I can insert Result and Senses with no conflict. But when I call Result from the database with LINQ query like this I get the Result object but my senses come null. 
**Question 1** Why and how can I solve it

```
var results =(from r in db.Results
         where r.headword == Id
         select r).ToList();
```

I try to add my senses to Result like this

```
 foreach (Result item in resultmodel.Results)
 {
     item.senses = (from s in db.Senses
                           join r in db.Results on s.res equals r
                           where r.Id_ == item.Id_
                           select s).ToList();
 }
```

I can add but when I try to show senses from my view I get

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

But I am waiting it would be a string 
**Question 2** what is wrong with my approach.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no problem if you convert your JSON string to the c# object. But in return, you want to map a string to object. What is that object? What are the properties? C# doesn't know anything about it.

One of my projects, I had a similar issue while writing and reading from Redis Cache server.
I added type definitions while serializing the object and deserialized with these types.

Serialize:

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, _settings);
return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
```

Deserialize:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString, _settings);
```

Settings:

```
private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings _settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
    Formatting = Formatting.None,
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: do you think problem comes from deserialize method? I can insert to databese without any problem. When I recall it break